# How to see if elements in two different lists of tuples match

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists of tuples that I am working with to eventually help me automate processes. I am looking to see how I can properly identify if there are matches in those lists of tuples.

I've already tried to flatten the lists of tuples to make them easier to work with and I'm thinking I want to identify if elements match with boolean statements but I'm not sure how to get the program to run through both lists of tuples.

```
list1 = [[('1306264304', 'Coca-Cola Zero Sugar Cola, Cans', '1'), ('1176982083', "Ito En Teas\\' Tea, Jasmine Green, Plastic Bottles", '1'), ('-975890652', "Ito En Teas\\' Tea, Lemongrass Green, Plastic Bottles", '1'), ('-1152939818', "Ito En Teas\\' Tea, Pure Green, Plastic Bottles", '1'), ('19102859', 'LaCroix Sparkling Water, Coconut, Cans', '1'), ('-546157568', 'LaCroix Sparkling Water, Grapefruit, Cans', '1')]] 

and

list2 = [[((beverages)'Coca-Cola Zero Sugar Cola, Cans', 4), ("Ito En Teas\\' Tea, Jasmine Green, Plastic Bottles", 3), ("Ito En Teas\\' Tea, Pure Green, Plastic Bottles", 5)]]
```

If a tuple element in list1 matches with a tuple element in list2, I need it to return true. For example: if 'Coca-Cola Zero Sugar Cola, Cans' appears in both lists, I need to get it to identify that match.  I am actually a little lost on how I should code this. I know I need a loop but that's about it. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the actual lists you are comparing? For example, list 1 has integers as characters `'1'` and list 2 has them as integers `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. The function is pretty well commented within, but essentially, we loop through one array and check each item against the item in the second array. If there is a match, we return true. If not, we return false.

```
# Create function
def find_match(arr1, arr2):
    # Loop through first array
    for item in arr1:
        # Given the current item, check it against items in other array
        for arr2_item in arr2:
            # Print what you are comparing
            print("array 1 item: ", item, "array 2 item: ", arr2_item)
            # If there is a match
            if item == arr2_item:
                # Return true
                return True
        # If not
        else:
            # Keep going
            continue
    # If you havent returned by this point, it means there is no match
    return False

# Main function
def main():
    # Example dummy list one
    list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    # Example dummy list two
    list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']

    # Call the function
    did_it_match = find_match(list1, list2)
    # Print the result
    print(did_it_match)

# Call main    
main()
```

*Note - your arrays you posted don't seem to be formatted correctly so I couldn't use those.*

**

### ** UPDATE PER OP SPECIFIED GUIDELINES **

**
The following code is edited from the other code sample posted but is a working solution with the arrays that OP posted.

```
def solution(list1, list2):
    for index, item in enumerate(list1[0]):
        for index, item2 in enumerate(list2[0]):

            for item3 in item:

                for item4 in item2:

                    if item3==item4:
                        return True

    return False

def main():
    list1 = [[('1306264304', 'Coca-Cola Zero Sugar Cola, Cans', '1'), ('1176982083', "Ito En Teas\\' Tea, Jasmine Green, Plastic Bottles", '1'), ('-975890652', "Ito En Teas\\' Tea, Lemongrass Green, Plastic Bottles", '1'), ('-1152939818', "Ito En Teas\\' Tea, Pure Green, Plastic Bottles", '1'), ('19102859', 'LaCroix Sparkling Water, Coconut, Cans', '1'), ('-546157568', 'LaCroix Sparkling Water, Grapefruit, Cans', '1')]] 
    list2 = [[('Coca-Cola Zero Sugar Cola, Cans', 4), ("Ito En Teas\\' Tea, Jasmine Green, Plastic Bottles", 3), ("Ito En Teas\\' Tea, Pure Green, Plastic Bottles", 5)]]

    does_match = solution(list1, list2)
    print(does_match)

main()
```

This returns **True**

Comment: Can you do this with tuples though? I'm looking for tuple elements in the array of tuples to match. The reason my arrays look like that is because that's how they look in my program. For context: I am getting my lists of tuples from a webpage I scraped and an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Should it be if ANY element in ANY tuple in array1 matches ANY element in ANY tuple in array2? Or should it be if the tuple in array 1 matches the tuple in array 2? Define the requirements more and I can help come up with a fix for you =)

Comment: Hmm upon giving it some more thought, I need to have the names match each other. So for example: the element 'Coca-Cola Zero Sugar Cola, Cans' in the tuple in array1 matches the element 'Coca-Cola Zero Sugar Cola, Cans' in the tuple in array2.

Comment: @TrentXavier this works using algoriyhtsmts solution. Please let us know if this worked.

Comment: @algoriyhtsmts it worked using this implementation. Thank you very much guys, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're looking for:

Since we can assume you have a list inside a list that has tuples inside it, this should do the trick:

```py
def function():
    for index, item in enumerate(list1[0]):
        for index, item2 in enumerate(list2[0]):

            for item3 in item:

                for item4 in item2:

                    if item3==item4:
                        return True
```

Comment: this is assuming your list1 and list2 variables are what you posted

Comment: I'm having difficulty implementing this solution though conceptually I can see it working. What do you think I am doing wrong? It returns 'none' instead of True or False.